# open multiple divs with jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I want to tab on a tab and open 2 divs. Like:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab1"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
        <li class="tab2"><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab1">this is tab1</div>
    <div id="tab2">this is tab2</div>
    <div id="tab3">this is tab3</div>
</div>
```

If I want to click tab1 tab, it shows both 'this is tab1' and 'this is tab3'. How can I achieve? Cheers.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean. Do you or don't you want multiple tabs to be open at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li class="tab1"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
    <li class="tab2"><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tab1">this is tab1</div>
<div id="tab2">this is tab2</div>

</div>

<!-- tab3 is outside of tabs and initially hidden -->
<div id="tab3" style="display:none;">this is tab3</div>

<script>
$(".tabs").tabs({activate: function() {
  /* if tab1 activated then show tab3 */
  if ($(".tabs").tabs("options","active") == 0 /* tab1 */) {
    $(".div3").show();
  } else {
    $(".div3").hide();
  }
}});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

minor update to Sergey's solution, param should be option, not options, see http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: You should put a comment under his answer to advise him of this so that he can update it, rather than brand new answer

Comment: Agreed with ▲. No matter whether this was a typo or new methods due to updated libraries, a comment would have been more appropriate. Another option would have been recommending an edit but I'm not sure if your rep allows that at this point.